# Sveltekit Error: `page` in `load` functions has been replaced by `url` and `params`

Tags: javascript, sveltekit

I am trying to display my date from GraphCMS in my blog application. I receive this error when I go to my single post link (http://localhost:3000/posts/union-types-and-sortable-relations)

"

`page` in `load` functions has been replaced by `url` and `params`
Error: `page` in `load` functions has been replaced by `url` and `params`

"

Here is my code

```js
<script context='module'>
    export const load = async ({fetch, page: {params}}) => {
        const {slug} = params
        const res = await fetch(`/posts/${slug}.json`)
        if(res.ok) {
            const {post} = await res.json()
            return {
                props: {post},
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<script>
    export let post
</script>


<svelte:head>
    <title>Emrah's Blog | Welcome</title>
</svelte:head>

<pre>{JSON.stringify(post, null, 2)}</pre>
```

Can you please help. Thanks

Comment: Do you mind accepting the answer if it was helpful?

Answer (score 3):

Try using `params` instead of `page: params`, though the latter still works in Sveltekit 278 (which I'm using).
Besides, I'm curious to know what makes you prefer this method to querying GraphCMS for your single post. I do it like this:

```js
import {client} from '$lib/js/graphql-client'
import {projectQuery} from '$lib/js/graphql-queries'

export const load = async ({ params }) => {
        const {slug} = params
        const variables = {slug}
        const {project} = await client.request(projectQuery, variables)

        return {
            props: {
                project
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this has been changed a while ago, now the different parts of what used to be `page` are passed directly into the load function:

```js
export async function load({ fetch, page }) {
 const { params, url } = page
}

export async function load({ fetch, params, url }) {
}
```

Something else to consider is that now there are `page endpoints`, if your file is `[slug].svelte` you can make a file `[slug].js` and add the following:

```js
export async function get({ params }) {
  const { slug } = params;
  const post = {}; // add the code to fetch from GraphCMS here
  return {
    status: 200,
    body: {
      post
    }
  }
}
```

With this you can remove the `load` function and make your code simpler (especially because you technically already have all this code in your `/posts/[slug].json.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script context='module'>
export async function load({ fetch, params}){
   
   
    let id = params.users
    const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`)
    const user = await response.json()
   
    if(response.ok){
        return  {props:{user}}
    }
    return {
        status: response.status,
        error : new Error(" sorry no user found")
    }
    }
```

export let user

[image]